# Trying to create a zoomable pic box

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use the code from
https://web.archive.org/web/20141229192708/http://bobpowell.net/zoompicbox.aspx
to create a zoomable pic box but I can't figure out if I could create a 'control' from it that I would then be able to drop onto the windows form.

Any help? Or thoughts

Answer (score 0):

IN that case, rather than a class, you would create a User Control.  The code shouldn't be too hard to transfer.